# How to add labels in verbatim env. in Latex?

Tags: cross-referencing, verbatim

I'm writing master thesis where I need to include some parts of program code. This code needs to be commented and properly described in text below/above. I would like to add some specific labels in the verbatim environment and use this labels as references in text. How can I do that?

Comment: Hi and Welcome to TeX.SX. You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) if you like.

Comment: Related [Is there a possibility to make reference to the line in the lstlisting environment?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/116216)

Comment: Could this code help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/216295/how-do-i-highlight-a-block-of-source-code-in-latex/219606#219606

Comment: Alternately, there is the `numberedblock` package, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/202966/how-can-i-show-codeboxes/202969#202969

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for your help guys. Based on question [Is there a possibility to make reference to the line in the lstlisting environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116216/is-there-a-possibility-to-make-reference-to-the-line-in-the-lstlisting-environme) I've finaly used following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\lstset{language=Pascal}
\lstset{escapeinside={(*@}{@*)}}
\begin{lstlisting}[frame=single, caption={Useless code}, label=useless_code, numbers=left]
 for i:=maxint to 0 do begin
   { comment }(*@\label{comment}@*) 
 end;
\end{lstlisting}
Line \ref{comment} of Listing~\ref{useless_code} shows a comment.

\end{document}
```

See following output:

[image: Output]

I know that it is not optimal solution, but for the purpose of my thesis seems to be sufficient solution.